# class attribute type pass by extends in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, generics, types, extends

In this case the type of state is correct.

```
export type Flatten<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never

class Foo<S> {
  state?: Partial<S>
}

class Bar<S> extends Foo<Flatten<S & { b: string }>> {
  async getInitialState(initialState: S) {
    return {
      ...initialState,
      b: 'bar'
    }
  }
}

const initialState = {
  a: 'baz'
}


class Baz extends Bar<typeof initialState> {
}

let baz = new Baz()
baz.state
// Partial<{
//   a: string;
//   b: string;
// }> | undefined
```

but in this case, the type of state will be override when assign a new value

```
class Baz extends Bar<typeof initialState> {
  state = initialState
}

let baz = new Baz()
baz.state
// {
//   a: string;
// }
```

I don't want to change the type of state in case 2. how should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass methods and properties are not [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) by base class methods and properties. That means TS won't be able to refer to the declared type `Partial<S>` for `state` from `Foo` base class in `Baz`, when you initialize the property.

Some time ago, there apparently was a related [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118) which had been aborted, because [cons outweighed the pros](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118#issuecomment-216595207) in real world applications. So, if you don't want to re-declare the `state` type in `Baz` like ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8BlAfNA3gKGtCALmAQKYD8AXNAApgBOBAlmCKmtgL7baiQwBC9NtBIAPUgDsAJjATIURUmww48kAJ4Tg0AOYkCASQmMmLBcRIAKRsdMhzpKigCUWXHmh19AVzoS3Hh4AdCE2Jsz2iiQANO6BAEZUAOTx9Elx0Fx4XFw88BKE0GF2DiTQALwB0GDJqQBe6bkE6gAOZaXClSjQAGRY0In4BHQ2OpncvFDQgnUi4iTSAkLNbfAAZkW2EaUq7oQWlDT0dqhRSCsk65vhZlFoGJXF21Gc3CD6A2CzlRIkAO7TL6WZzYepBfakbAAeihRwYESQOBhHhqQxGEh0AG5obC8INCOisTjMhgAD7QbzSEhrGwkKRAA)):

```
type State<S> = S & { b: string }

class Bar<S> extends Foo<State<S>> { }

class Baz extends Bar<typeof initialState> {
  state?: Partial<State<typeof initialState>> = initialState
}
```

, you could pass the `initialValue` declared with an explicit corresponding type to `Baz`:

```
const partialInitialState: Partial<State<typeof initialState>> | undefined = initialState

class Baz extends Bar<typeof initialState> {
  state = partialInitialState
}
```

Further links

- [Contextual typing for subclass properties](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3667)
- [Contextual typing for subclass methods](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373)
- [TS spec contextual typing](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#15-contextual-typing)
- Related issues: [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2073) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1887)