# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I've defined the following `interface`:

```
export interface Data {
  visibleAction: string
  actionsVisibility: {
    actionForms: boolean
    backButton: boolean
    createAccount: boolean
    login: boolean
  }
  actionsHistory: string[]
  userID: string
}
```

which is later implemented on the class:

```
export default class userManager extends Vue implements Data {
  actionsVisibility = {
    login: false,
    createAccount: false,
    backButton: false,
    actionForms: false
  }
  visibleAction = `login`
  actionsHistory = []
  userID = ``

  hideUserActionForm () {
    this.actionsVisibility[this.visibleAction] = false
  }
  ... other logic
}
```

For the line `this.actionsVisibility[this.visibleAction] = false` TS warns with the error:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ login: boolean; createAccount: boolean; backButton: boolean; actionForms: boolean; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ login: boolean; createAccount: boolean; backButton: boolean; actionForms: boolean; }'.
```

Can you please suggest how approach the followin typecism :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent the error "Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type" when compiling typescript with noImplicitAny flag enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.visibleAction` in `userManager` class gets a `string` type in your case and you cannot use `string` to access `this.actionsVisibility` as computed property name, hence an error is triggered.

In addition, a TS design limitation is that class properties like `visibleAction` do not get a [contextual type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) from base types like `Data`, so you need to annotate types in the class again. If you hover over the class properties, you notice that some do not match the interface types - more explanations in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58338400/class-attribute-type-pass-by-extends-in-typescript/58344423#58344423).

**A possible solution**

Give `visibleAction` in `Data` and `userManager` an explicit type `keyof Data["actionsVisibility"]`, which is the union of string keys of `actionsVisibility` ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=27&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEUxkzgG8BYAKDhrgDcEBnBAIwBtgBBbGBCJAFxwA1sACeEdASKYA2gCIcvfowBqTVgjYIYY%20QF0qtOEr5I1Gllp1ihFasdqn%20AMWgBbRkJYQIHTEhGjjQsOMIAQgCuMDD83r7%20gQ7B2FDARFzY2BCRKPF%206UnBNGwQAObI%20YlBNAC%20NSY8ZowAEkyxULZwjDBQyGWyhslwkYxoAJL4Qj19SGVU9ZRUoJCwcAAmwFiRbPDYbJiMjCNjUACyAZhlaIjuYBzuwCjHhMRkDc7m6sxW2rpwAF53sNjKUKoI4Fg2GMADQNYypdKobjZXIwIRQ2Hw2ihbARaKxCGY4BwkFOJquDxeSGYaHABqLYwMH4cbjKCGiCRSV5yRQUr6Way6AyAuAAAzByDFH35rXa0DEosGDVGE3worF0qWwwAFghNgBVU5ssxuKDuAAUAEpgcU4DA9YwAHSfCw-IViWQOphO5msVn8-Si4kMhZAA)):

```
export interface Data {
    visibleAction: keyof Data["actionsVisibility"] // change this type
    actionsVisibility: {
        actionForms: boolean
        backButton: boolean
        createAccount: boolean
        login: boolean
    }
    ...
}

export default class userManager implements Data {
    actionsVisibility = {
        login: false,
        createAccount: false,
        backButton: false,
        actionForms: false
    }
    visibleAction: keyof Data["actionsVisibility"] = `login` // change this type
    ...

    hideUserActionForm() {
        this.actionsVisibility[this.visibleAction] = false // works now
    }
}
```